# I can't connect multiple pages in phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, cordova

I 'm using build.phonegap.com, HTML5, CSS3 and Javascript for developing an android app. And I'm pulling in the code to build.phonegap.com through github. All of my codes are hosted in github. In first page of android app, there is a button. When I press it, it should redirect to next page. All of my HTML5, CSS3 and Javascript coded pages aren't hosted in live server. They are hosted in local server. How can I make a page redirect to another page under such situations?

Answer (score 0):

If you are loading your html pages from remote server, you need to add your servers domain to `whitelist` in the config.xml.

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.5.0/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html

Comment: What if we are hosting them in local server?

Comment: If you can not connect to your server from outside, then there's obviously no way to load anything from there. You need to have a domain or ip of your server. For getting help setting it up you have to make another question.